# unable to show the selected text data in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Clicking on a text displaying that text in url but unable to show that text in view file.

View:

```
<div class="applynow"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>career/apply/<?php echo $r->job_name;?>" class="applyforjob">Apply Now</a></div>
```

Clicking on the apply now button displaying the job name in URL.
But The job name is not dislaying in view file.

Controller:career/apply

```
function apply()
{
    $this->load->model('career_model');
    $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['mainpage']='apply';            
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Career Model:

```
function getcareerdatas($id)
{
    $this->db->select('jobs_list.*');       
    $this->db->from('jobs_list');
    $this->db->where(array('jobs_list.job_name'=>$id));
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form name="applynow"  id="applynow" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>apply/applynow">

            <div class ="applyus">  
            <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>              
            <span class="digit"><?php echo $r->job_name ;?></span>
            <?php endforeach;endif;?>

                    <div class="applyfullname contactname">
                        <label for="fullname"><font color="black">Full Name</font><span class="mandatory"><font color ="red">*</font></span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control names" name="fullname" id="fullname " value="<?php echo set_value('fullname');?>" placeholder="Full Name">   
                        <?php echo form_error('fullname', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="applynowemail contactemail">
                    <label for="email"><font color="black">Email</font><span class="mandatory"><font color ="red">*</font></span></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" placeholder="Email" >
                        <?php echo form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>                         
                    </div>
```

Clicking on apply now button it will open another page in that page it is not displaying the job name.

MYSQL:

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| jobs_id |      job_name      |     jobs_name      | job_description |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|       1 | Junior QA Enginner | Junior_QA_Enginner | Description     |
|       2 | Junior Engineer    | Junior_Enginner    | Description     |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: ```$this->db->where(array('jobs_list.job_name'=>$id));``` from this line I come to know that, your ```job_name``` nothing but numeric id.So which thing you want??

Comment: @kishor10d it is storing the text vale which is displaying correctly in URL but not displaying in Form

Comment: Try `$this->db->select('*');` instead of `$this->db->select('jobs_list.*');`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 its not working

Comment: have you checked that data is coming from database or not - using ```print_r()``` or etc.

Comment: can you update your question with table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First view is like (take `job_id` instead `job_name` in url) :

```
<div class="applynow"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>career/apply/<?php echo $r->jobs_id;?>" class="applyforjob">Apply Now</a></div>
```

Now, after clicking on this your controller be like (no need of segment, you can take value of querystring as parameter of function in codeigniter) :

```
function apply($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('career_model');
    $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);
    $data['mainpage']='apply';            
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Then your model is (change your query to compare with `job_id` instead `job_name`) :

```
function getcareerdatas($id)
{
    $this->db->select('jobs_list.*');       
    $this->db->from('jobs_list');
    $this->db->where('jobs_list.jobs_id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get();        

    return $q->result();
}
```

Keep the view as it is. If you get matching record with your `$jobs_id` then you definitely get data in `$records2`.

Try this solution.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [jobs_id] => 1 [job_name] => Digital Marketing Associate [jobs_name] => [job_description] =>

Comment: It is displaying all the data  as well including description everything

Comment: all data??? have you confirmed that what is coming as ```$job_id```? have you check all the instructions??

Comment: It is coming 1 in the url and in the form it is displaying text

Comment: Is it not possible to display Text in the url instead of id

Comment: Need to add this job name while sending an email

Comment: yes solved but need to display name in url instead of id

Comment: for that purpose you need to implement slug in your application. If you got resolution of your first problem then please accept the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150070/discussion-between-kishor10d-and-user8001297).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
function getcareerdatas($id)
{

   $this->db->where('job_name', $id);
   $q = $this->db->get('jobs_list');        

   if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $q->result();
   } else {
      return array();
   }
}
```

Make sure your controller has first letter upper case only.

On controller echo $this->uri->segment(3) make sure you are getting correct

Update

Remove  `&& is_array($records2)` just for testing.

```
<?php if(isset($records2)) {?>
// Other data 
<?php }?>
```

Comment: In URL i am getting the name

Comment: @wolfgand1983 : thumbs up for update. When we fetch ```result()``` it nothing but the Standard Class Object (not array).

Comment: Getting this error :A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You might be only returning one item only not multiple

Comment: @user8001297 : You don't have any data with your variable ```$records2```, please try to print the data in controller itself like ```print_r($data["records2"]); die;```

Comment: @kishor10d not displaying anything if i print in controller

Comment: It means you have problem with your query. You didn't get anything from database. please check that what is ```$this->uri->segment(3)``` giving any data or not (as @wolfgang1983 already mention it in solution)

Comment: @kishor10d i have tried that as well but not getting any thing

Comment: printed the data not getting any data n CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #23 [result_id] => Resource id #26 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [row_data] => )

Comment: hence you don't have any records which meets your query. Please check the query and records also.

Comment: Everything is perfect in your code, you just miss the ```$id``` value in your query. I don't think your ```job_name``` is a numeric value. I think you are comparing ```$id``` numeric with ```$job_name``` varchar.

Comment: @kishor10d not getting what you are saying

Comment: @kishor10d job_name it is storing text value i mean to say "JUNIOR QA ENGINEER" it will store in this format

Comment: what is your primary key of the table?? is it job id??

Comment: @kishor10d yes jobs_id is a primary key i have updated my question with table structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150078/discussion-between-kishor10d-and-user8001297).